# Uploading a file to google drive via API fails

Tags: go, google-drive-api, mime-types

I am trying to upload a file to my Google Drive, however it fails. I think I've specified the MIME type correctly, as I've seen that this is a common problem, but it still doesn't work for me.

About the conversion systems: I have an API with Gin-Gonic (v1.9.1) where I upload a file. The file is successfully passed from the frontend/postman to the API, since I can successfully save the file I get from the API.

The error I get is:

> Post "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?alt=json&prettyPrint=false&uploadType=multipart": Post "": unsupported protocol scheme ""

I have the following function:

```golang
func (c *Client) UploadFile(oauthTokenConfig GoogleOauthTokenConfig, parentFolderId string, fileHeader *multipart.FileHeader) (*string, error) {
    svc, err := drive.NewService(context.Background(), option.WithHTTPClient(
        oauthTokenConfig.Config.Client(
            context.Background(),
            &oauth2.Token{
                AccessToken:  oauthTokenConfig.AccessToken,
                TokenType:    oauthTokenConfig.TokenType,
                RefreshToken: oauthTokenConfig.RefreshToken,
                Expiry:       oauthTokenConfig.ExpiresIn,
            },
        )),
    )
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    fileExtension := filepath.Ext(fileHeader.Filename)
    fileName := strings.TrimSuffix(fileHeader.Filename, fileExtension)
    fileMimeType := fileHeader.Header.Get("Content-Type")
    uploadFileMetaData := drive.File{
        Name:     fmt.Sprintf("%s%s", fileName, fileExtension), 
                // fmt.Sprintf("%s_%s%s", fileName, uuid.New().String(), fileExtension),
        Parents:  []string{parentFolderId},
        MimeType: fileMimeType,
    }

    file, err := fileHeader.Open()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer file.Close()

    fileResult, err := svc.Files.
        Create(&uploadFileMetaData).
        Media(file, googleapi.ContentType("text/plain")).
        Do()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err // here I get the error
    }

        // ...

}
```

I have added here the MIME type hardcoded however the variable `fileMimeType` is actually correct. I upload a Test.txt file with the content Test1 (the file is also created successfully when I send it via Frontend/Postman). I have also tried to dynamically specify the file MIME type or no MIME-type at all, but always with the same result.

---

I use the following packages for this:

- go version: `go1.21.1 darwin/arm64`
- go list -m golang.org/x/oauth2: v0.13.0
- go list -m google.golang.org/api: v0.147.0

  - google.golang.org/api/drive/v3
  - google.golang.org/api/googleapi
  - google.golang.org/api/option

EDIT:

I have also replicated the [official example from Google](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client/blob/main/examples/drive.go) and it still doesn't work.

Comment: you get 'unsupported protocol scheme'error when you proide invalid url.

Comment: @ABDULLOKHMUKHAMMADJONOV What is invalid about the url, I don't set a url, but take the default url from the package? Is there a way to overwrite or correct the URL or the scheme.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looked like the error was with the authentication. It's a bit difficult to deduce the invalid authentication from this error, but I had to change the refresh algorithm for the refresh token a bit to make it work.

---

Here is my working code. Note that before I call the `UploadFile()` function, I first check the `oauthTokenConfig.ExpiresIn` to see if the token is still valid, if so I upload the file, otherwise I first refresh the token.

File-upload

```golang
func (c *Client) UploadFile(oauthTokenConfig GoogleOauthTokenConfig, parentFolderId string, file *multipart.FileHeader) (*string, error) {
    svc, err := drive.NewService(context.Background(), option.WithHTTPClient(
        oauthTokenConfig.Config.Client(
            context.Background(),
            &oauth2.Token{
                AccessToken:  oauthTokenConfig.AccessToken,
                TokenType:    oauthTokenConfig.TokenType,
                RefreshToken: oauthTokenConfig.RefreshToken,
                Expiry:       oauthTokenConfig.ExpiresIn,
            },
        )),
    )
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to create drive-service: %s", err.Error())
    }

    fileExtension := filepath.Ext(file.Filename)
    fileName := strings.TrimSuffix(file.Filename, fileExtension)
    uploadFile := drive.File{
        Name:    fmt.Sprintf("%s_%s%s", fileName, uuid.New().String(), fileExtension),
        Parents: []string{parentFolderId},
    }
    fileContent, err := file.Open()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to open file: %s", err.Error())
    }

    fileResult, err := svc.Files.Create(&uploadFile).Media(fileContent).Do()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to create file: %s", err.Error())
    }

    uploadedFile, err := svc.Files.Get(fileResult.Id).Fields("webViewLink").Do()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to get file: %s", err.Error())
    }
    return &uploadedFile.WebViewLink, nil
}
```

Refresh-token

```golang
func (c *Client) RefreshToken(oauthTokenConfig GoogleOauthTokenConfig) (*GoogleOauthTokenConfig, error) {
    ctx := context.Background()
    config := oauth2.Config{
        ClientID:     c.ClientId,
        ClientSecret: c.ClientSecret,
        RedirectURL:  oauthTokenConfig.Config.RedirectURL,
        Scopes:       []string{"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"},
        Endpoint:     google.Endpoint,
    }

    token := &oauth2.Token{
        AccessToken:  oauthTokenConfig.AccessToken,
        TokenType:    oauthTokenConfig.TokenType,
        RefreshToken: oauthTokenConfig.RefreshToken,
        Expiry:       oauthTokenConfig.ExpiresIn,
    }

    tokenSource := config.TokenSource(ctx, token)

    updatedToken, err := tokenSource.Token()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return &GoogleOauthTokenConfig{
        Config:       config,
        AccessToken:  updatedToken.AccessToken,
        RefreshToken: updatedToken.RefreshToken,
        ExpiresIn:    updatedToken.Expiry,
        TokenType:    updatedToken.TokenType,
    }, nil
}
```